# Difference between passing in null and undefined in useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

What's the difference between `useRef(null)` and `useRef(undefined)` (or just `useRef()`)?

In TypeScript, the results end up with different types:

```
const undefinedRef: React.MutableRefObject<undefined> = useRef(undefined)
conse noArgRef: React.MutableRefObject<undefined> = useRef()

const nullRef: React.MutableRefObject<null> = useRef(null)
```

This also has further consequences, when passing the ref to another element:

```
const nullRef = useRef(null)
<div ref={nullRef} /> // this works

const undefinedRef = useRef()
<div ref={undefinedRef} /> // compiler failure!
/*
Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.ts(2322)
*/
```

Despite the compiler failure, it still works for my use case (using the `useClickAway` hook from `react-use`)

What's the impact at this, looking beyond the TypeScript types?

Here's a CodeSandbox that recreates the failure: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-resonance-j9yuu?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 6):

There isn't any difference between

```
const undefinedRef: React.MutableRefObject<undefined> = useRef(undefined)
conse noArgRef: React.MutableRefObject<undefined> = useRef()
```

both of them have `undefinedRef.current` and `noArgRef.current` as undefined.

However

```
const nullRef: React.MutableRefObject<null> = useRef(null)
```

will have `nullRef.current` assigned as null

The only impact this will have in your code is when you actually try to access a property from within current or try to check the typeof ref

For instance `typeof nullRef.current` will be `object`

and an if condition like

```
if(typeof nullRef.current === "object") {
   // This will get executed only for nullRef and not for the other two refs
}
```

Comment: I updated my original post with some more context. Both `useRef()` and `useRef(null)` work at runtime (for my use case), but they have different compiler results. Do you have any insights here?

Comment: Surprisingly I don't see any compiler error. Do you use serverside rendering?

Comment: I use client side rendering. See my original post for a CodeSandbox that recreates the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I believe something like `const ref = useRef<SomeType>(null)` will make the reference readonly.

See [this note from TypeScript cheatsheet](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet/issues/187#issuecomment-587496848).

> there are overloads for useRef such that if you use a type param T vs
>   T | null the resultant object is different:
>
> ```
> refObjectToPassIntoRefProp = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null) // @type = {
> current: HTMLDivElement | null } const refObjectYouMaintain =
> useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null) // @type = { current:
> HTMLDivElement | undefined } const refObjectYouMaintainToo =
> useRef<HTMLDivElement>()
> ```
>
> With the first, the current property of the object is read-only to
>   you, the consumer. It's meant to be passed into React as the pointer
>   is maintained by React. In practice, you can still mutate the current
>   property of something you pass into React but it's not recommended as
>   React is supposed to be the owner.