# How do I use useRef in my jsx file as it is showing MutableRefObject errror?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
 const handleClick = (direction) => {
    let distance = listRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x - 50

    if (listRef.current) {
      if (direction === "left" && slideNumber > 0) {
        setSlideNumber(slideNumber - 1)
        listRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${230 + distance}px)`
      } else if (direction === "right" && slideNumber < 5) {
        setSlideNumber(slideNumber + 1)
        listRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${-230 + distance}px)`
      }
    }
```

can't use `listRef.current` inside my handle click function.

1. showing:`React.MutableRefObject.current<undefined>`error

I'm working on a jsx file so I want this reference in jsx

Comment: There's a bit of a contradiction here. You have `if (listRef.current)` which means you expect `listRef.current` to not always have a truthy value, but you're using it before that check as though it always has a value

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61635121/difference-between-passing-in-null-and-undefined-in-useref

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare the distance after you have checked if the ref.current exists. If you could also post how you declared your ref would be helpful.

```
const handleClick = (direction) => {
    if (listRef.current) {
      const distance = listRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x - 50
      if (direction === "left" && slideNumber > 0) {
        setSlideNumber(slideNumber - 1)
        listRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${230 + distance}px)`
      } else if (direction === "right" && slideNumber < 5) {
        setSlideNumber(slideNumber + 1)
        listRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${-230 + distance}px)`
      }
    }
```